# BCrypt - "no such file to load -- bcrypt" (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt-ruby

As the title suggests! Here are the relevant files/configs:

```
$ gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

Ascii85 (1.0.2)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
hashery (2.0.1)
pdf-reader (1.2.0)
prawn (0.12.0)
ruby-rc4 (0.1.5)
ttfunk (1.0.3)

$ grep bcrypt Gemfile
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

$ grep bcrypt Gemfile.lock 
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
bcrypt-ruby
```

Any "require bcrypt" causes the error. I've run bundle install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR, I'm an idiot. Restarting the app fixed it.

```
$ touch tmp/restart.txt
```

Comment: don't worry, you are not the only idiot :P . and thanks